# how to connect SQL server from oracle in SQL developer

Tags: sql-server, oracle, oracle-sql-developer

I have two connections in SQL developer that one of them is SQL server (A) and the other one is oracle (B).
how can I make a database link between this two connections from (B) to (A) to select connection A data from connection B?

Comment: It really has nothing to do with 'connections', as defined in SQL Dev.  That is just a construct within SQL Dev to define how it connects to a particular database.  SQL Dev is just a client to any one database. While you can have SQL Dev connections concurrently open to multiple databases, those connections have no more to do with each other than two separate invocations of sqlplus, each connected to a different db.  If you want to access an oracle db from an MSSQL db, you create a 'shared server' in the MSSQL.  If you want to go the other way, create a DB Link in the oracle DB.

Comment: HIt the space limit in my previous response.  In order to better understand the concepts, you might find this blog article ineresting: http://edstevensdba.com/oracle-heterogeneous-communication/oracle-transparent-gateway/.   And remember, this is not a SQL Developer question.

Comment: @EdStevens - hitting your limit on a comment is a good indication that you are writing an `Answer`, not a `Comment`.

Answer (score 1):

The last time I looked (and that's quite a number of years ago), you needed Oracle Gateway to establish such a link.

Just checked, the product is still around: Oracle Database Gateway for SQL Server.